# Concatenate Strings in Knockout

Tags: knockout.js

I need to concatenate a url parameter onto an anchor tag.  How would I go about insert it into the following template?

```
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: Customers">
            <tr class="rowEven">
                <td data-bind="text: Name"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: CustomerType"></td>
                <td><a href="customers.aspx?customer=[CustomerAccountIDHere]">Manage</a><a href="#">Guest Admin</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
```

I tried this will no luck:

```
            <tr class="rowEven">
                <td data-bind="text: Name"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: CustomerType"></td>
                <td><a data-bind="attr: { href: 'customers.aspx?customer=' + CustomerAccount_BID}">Manage</a><a href="#">Guest Admin</a></td>
            </tr>
```

Comment: What does your ViewModel look like?

Comment: I think the viewmodel might be the issue, here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/L4hUq/

Comment: @Kendaleiv post that as an answer, I'll accept.  I had the property name wrong....

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think the viewmodel might be the issue, here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/L4hUq

Answer (score 12):

Add "()" - **CustomerAccount_BID()** works for me.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this....

```
$(function()
{

    var myViewModel1 = function () {
        var self = this;
        self.firstName = ko.observable("Kamalakar");
        self.lastName = ko.observable("Ashtankar");
        self.fullName = ko.pureComputed(function () {
            return self.firstName() + " " + self.lastName();
        }
        );
    };

    ko.applyBindings(myViewModel1);

});
```