# knockout concatenate issue

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am trying to the following but it's not working:

```
<!-- ko foreach: _Poi_Images_List -->
  <img data-bind='attr: {alt: "images/"+ PATH }'  />
<!-- /ko -->
```

when I remove the "images/"+  part it works, but as soon as I add it. it messes up with javascript and not the actual PATH i want, and it becomes like this:

```
<span data-bind="attr: {alt: "images/"+ PATH }" alt="images/Poi/function c(){if(0&lt;arguments.length){if(!c.equalityComparer||!c.equalityComparer(d,arguments[0]))c.I(),d=arguments[0],c.H();return this}a.U.La(c);return d}"></span>
```

any ideas?
I have already checked this reference for the concatenation part and I basically did the same:
[Concatenate Strings in Knockout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12013594/concatenate-strings-in-knockout)

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to unwrap observable when use it in expression. Change your code to this:

```
<!-- ko foreach: _Poi_Images_List -->
  <img data-bind='attr: {alt: "images/"+ PATH() }'  />
<!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: thanks! works

if you can help me with this too? when i check a box, they're all being checked...
_Poi_Categories_List has all the items,
and My_Pois_category is the empty list where I want to have each id added

<!-- ko foreach: _Poi_Categories_List -->
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="attr: {value: $data}, checked: My_Pois_category" /><span data-bind="text: CODE"></span><br />
<!-- /ko -->